# Static Tab with placeholder values not displayed

Tags: json, microsoft-teams

I am currently getting into Microsoft Team Apps and am trying to create a very simple tool.

All it should be is a static tab, that when visited embeds a certain website, that's given the `groupId` as a parameter. This is the format, that I have in mind for the `contentUrl: https://foo.bar?groupId=\{groupId\}`

The app consists only of two images, that are PNGs in 20x20px (transparent) and 96x96px (with background color) and the manifest (version 1.2).

The manifest contains all required fields:

`$schema`, `manifestVersion`, `version`, `id`, `packageName`, `developer {name, websiteUrl, privacyUrl, termsOfUseUrl}`, `icons {color, outline}`, `description {short, full}`, `accentColor`, `permissions`, `validDomains`, `staticTabs [{entityId, name, contentUrl, scopes}]`

An Id for the app has been generated at [`apps.dev.microsoft.com`](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).

The upload of the custom app as zip file causes no error and I can see the app in the list of the installed applications. If I switch to a channel I can't see the tab which should be there without being explicitly added because it's a static tab. Adding it manually isn't possible because it's not shown in the list of "addable apps".

I tried some of the [example apps](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs) from GitHub, but they seem outdated and at least partly can't be even read (`Error while reading manifest.json`).

Is this sufficient information to help me?

**Edit:** (anonymized `manifest.json`)

```
{
  "$schema":
    "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.2/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "12345678-abcd-efgh-1234-123456789012",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.bar",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Foo Corp",
    "websiteUrl": "https://foo.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://foo.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://foo.com/termsofuse"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "src/images/waldo-96x96.png",
    "outline": "src/images/waldo-20x20.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "bar",
    "full": "bar"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Opens baz and does qux.",
    "full": "Opens baz and does qux."
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "permissions": ["identity", "messageTeamMembers"],
  "validDomains": ["*.baz.com", "*.foo.com"],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "tabId",
      "name": "example tab",
      "contentUrl":
        "https://foo.com/?teamId={teamId}&teamName={teamName}&channelId={channelId}&channelName={channelName}&locale={locale}&theme={theme}&entityId={entityId}&subEntityId={subEntityId}&upn={upn}&tid={tid}&groupId={groupId}&theme={theme}&isFullScreen={isFullScreen}",
      "scopes": ["personal"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Static tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-static) declared in personal scope are always pinned to the app's personal experience. Static tabs do not currently support the 'teams' scope. Could you please verify if you are adding teams scope to static tab? If not please share the maifest code.

Comment: I am also open for other implementations. Just getting Context Information and giving them as parameters to a website you want to embed seemed so simple as an idea ^^

Comment: Please check the [configurable tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview#what-you-need-to-know-configurable-tabs) documentation. This are configured in a channel inside particular team. You could [retrieve the context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context#accessing-context) information easily.

Comment: So the approach in this case would be to create an empty HTML page as "configuration page" that just runs some JS to store the context information, that I need and then display the content page with these as parameters? That sounds kind of "hacky" if I understood it correctly - I will test that :)

Comment: This works great. Thank you @Wajeed-MSFT.

Answer (score 1):

I could see two issues in your manifest code:

1. Invalid GUID: 12345678-abcd-efgh-1234-123456789012 is not valid GUID.
2. Icons must be included in the package and referenced via relative paths in the manifest.

   ex. waldo-96x96.png - Please place them inside zip file.

Please feel free to use [Teams App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio#manifest-editor) to create the manifest file. You can also use the existing form the [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp/tree/master/Microsoft.Teams.Samples.HelloWorld.Web/Manifest).

Comment: 1. I replaced the ID. The actual one was created in the app portal - so it is valid.

2. The icons are included and working.

Comment: Is it showing your app in personal scope? 
Try this: Click on Store =>Upload a custom App => select your package => Click Install

Comment: I always added it for a team:

Team -> Manage Team -> Apps -> Upload a custom app -> ...

Now I can see the tab - that's progress, thank you for that :)

But it only partially transfers the data I want to send. *upn* and *tid* work but *groupId* is empty. Do I need special permissions for them?

Comment: URL looks like:
https://foo.bar/teamId={teamId}&teamName={teamName}&channelId={channelId}&channelName={channelName}&locale={locale}&theme={theme}&entityId={entityId}&subEntityId={subEntityId}& **upn={upn}** & **tid={tid}** & *groupId={groupId}* &theme={theme}&isFullScreen={isFullScreen}

**what I get** *what I need*